# Angular-material:- Change default icon for mat-expansion-panel in accordion

Tags: angular, angular-material

Below is the link of Stackblitz I am trying to change the icon(arrow) with image/some other icon. Instead of down arrow I am trying to have plus sign arrow.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wwpb6y?file=styles.css

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show us your effort.

Comment: I was able to change the color but I dont have any idea about icon,I did inspect using chrome developer tools but couldn't find anything

Comment: It's not an icon you see. It's just CSS using borders so it looks like arrow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give your expansion panel a reference id `example` and set the `hideToggle` property as `true`. 
place your icons in `<mat-panel-description>` and use the expanded property of the panel to show or hide the relevant icons.

```
 <mat-expansion-panel  class="custom-header" hideToggle="true" #example>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Collapsible Group Item #1
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description> 
        <mat-icon *ngIf="!example.expanded">add</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="example.expanded">add_box</mat-icon>
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

     <p>
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
    </p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
```

CSS:

```
.custom-header .mat-expansion-panel-header-title, 
.custom-header .mat-expansion-panel-header-description {
  flex-basis: 0;
}

.custom-header .mat-expansion-panel-header-description {
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Also check on link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-irnxvd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: Thanks..........

Comment: is there a way to generate `id` dynamically for multiple expansion panels?

Comment: @Zuber I have done something. try if it is work for you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmbtmz?file=src/app/app.component.css

Comment: @Abhishek doesn't work

Comment: @zuber this solution should work for multiple expansion panels.

Comment: @Cornelius Look at this link i think this can help you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nurirf?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: @Abhishek actually the proposed solution works, with a single #, but I'm not sure if it's a correct approach, but it worked